# Something new in old question about sums of three polynomial cubes ?

Tags: polynomials, nt.number-theory, open-problems

An old problem asks whether or not the polynomial 
$$
t \in \mathbb{Q}[t]
$$
is a sum of three cubes, (of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$).

Question: Something new known now ?
Somebody has an idea of what to try  (besides searching the literature available)?

It is well known and easy to write $t$ as a sum of four cubes.
Also, certainly, $t$ cannot be a sum of two cubes.

More precisely:
(a) $t$ is a sum of $4$ cubes in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ since
$$
t =(t/6+1)^3- (t/6)^3 - (t/6)^3 +(t/6-1)^3
$$
Some variants are

(b) $t$ is a sum $3$ cubes in $\mathbb{Q}[2^{1/3}][t]$ since
$$
t =(t/6+1)^3- {(2^{1/3} t/6)}^3 +(t/6-1)^3
$$

(c) $t$ is a sum $3$ cubes in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ since
$$
t =((t^3-1/27)^3+ {(t^2+ t/3)}^3 +(-t^3+t/3+1/27)^3)/(t^2+t/3+1/9)^3
$$

Comment: It is also well-known that, since $(t+1)^3-2t^3+(t-1)^3=6t$, there are solutions if you take your coefficients from an appropriate number field. 

Comment: Your formula is the same formula that proves $4$ cubes over $\mathbb{Q}$
just change $t$ into $t/6.$

Comment: Edited using Gerry's idea above.
@Gerry: Using your idea and the `tangent-chord`  method you can build
in the surface $t=x^3+y^3+z^3,$
more solutions $(x,y,z)  \in  {Q[2^{1/3}][t]}^3.$ I do not know if all these solutions are forced or not
to be always outside of  $Q[t]^3.$



Comment: At least, $t$ is not the sum of three cubes in $\Bbb Z[t]$ because taking the derivative of $t = a(t)^3+b(t)^3+c(t)^3$ with respect to $t$ would yield $$1 \;=\; 3 a'(t) a(t)^2  +   3 b'(t) b(t)^2   +   3 c'(t) c(t)^2 \equiv 0  \pmod 3,$$ which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 3):

I looked it up on MathSciNet, but it seems that all the recent papers on the subject are (at least co-)authored by one Luis H Gallardo. Perhaps you can ask him?

Comment: Fantastic: I discover from your ànswer` that I have published on sums of cubes
of rational polynomials !!!. Can you precise the title of paper, please ?

Comment: @Igor: I am not sure that such moking answers are really constructive.

Comment: @Luis: a search for "cubes" and "polynomials" in some combination, brings up some completely unrelated papers, and a bunch of papers co-authored by you (admittedly, not over $\mathbb{Q}.$ @Andrei: I don't disagree with you. I had a dim recollection of the foundational paper by Vaserstein, so figured if there were any progress, the paper would cite this. However, all the citing papers were co-authored by Luis, which, to me means that he is the world expert in the field. No insult was meant.